# In Affinity Designer Desktop, How do i select shapes that are not completely bounded by marquee area

Tags: selections, affinity-designer, marquee-tool

In Affinity Designer Desktop, How do i select shapes that are not completely bounded by marquee area, similar to Adobe Illustrator marquee tool.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a tool option in the preferencs for it. Activate option "Select object when intersects the selection marquee"